# Libgdx Google play service crash

Tags: libgdx

A ver chicos llevo con este problema mucho tiempo, y no lo he podido arreglar, espero que me puedan dar una manita.

*Estoy usando eclipse luna

*Uso LibGDX

*Mi app tiene anuncios

En muy pocos dispositivos mi app hace crash, en la mayoría la app trabaja muy bien, el crash report es el siguiente:

```
09-11 19:31:59.656: E/AndroidRuntime(7022): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 19:31:59.656: E/AndroidRuntime(7022): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
09-11 19:31:59.656: E/AndroidRuntime(7022):     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzs.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Tras leer algunas preguntas similares, algunas respuestas sugerian que añadiera `android-support-v4.jar`

Bueno, lo añadi de la siguiente forma, arrastre el jar a la carpeta de `lib` en el `proyecto-android`
Luego le hice click derecho en el `proyecto-android`

properties->java build path->Libraries->Add Jars
  y aqui añadi el jar que habia puesto en la carpeta `lib`

Y ahora el siguiente error ocurre:

[`2016-09-11 19:33:41 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 
[2016-09-11 19:33:41 - proyecto-android] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536`

Gracias en adelantado!

Answer (score 4):

Al añadir el jar lo que ha pasado es que has sobrepasado el número máximo de metodos(65k!) entre tu proyecto y librerías.

Tienes dos soluciones, o añadir solo la parte concreta de `android-support-v4` que necesitas o activar el multidexing.

Lo que no sabría decirte es como arreglar esto usando el Eclipse (Sin gradle), este problema exacto fue el que me hizo migrar mis desarrollos `Libgdx` de *Eclipse* a *IntelliJ*.

[Mi recomendación y la de más gente es que migres a otro IDE (IntelliJ, Android Studio).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586675/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536-in-eclipse)

[Esta pregunta ya habia sido contestada en SOeng (no para Eclipse).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

[Solución usando multidex por parte de Google.](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

**EDIT (Solución usando gradle):**

Normalmente el import que suele ser el culpable es el de GooglePlay-services, la solucion por tanto es solo traernos la parte necesaria de los services. En tu caso seria los anuncios:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:versionQueUses'
}
```

Comment: te contesto por aca por que todavia no puede añadir comentarios, dices que no sabrias soluccionar este problema sin gradle, pero libgdx usa gradle, sabrias arreglarlo con gradle? Gracias compa

Comment: He editado mi respuesta.